# Bundle Warning creating android project xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

Im having this issue where I create an empty project and then I create and android project within that, Now if I go to the Main.cs or create my own activity, the Bundle is underlined and on hover I get the following error, As seen below.

[image]

Zoomed : 
[image]

I haven't changed Anything at all, this is what I get when opening the .cs files.

I just want to know if this is going to affect my app or not, and what is causing it.

Thanks in advance for Your Help

ps. Criticism is very much welcomed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two warnings there neither of which will affect your application.

**Warning: Parameter name differs in base method declaration** - This means that the name of the parameter is different to the one in the base class. It is called **savedInstanceState** in the base class. So you can get rid of this warning by changing the parameter so it has the same name. The real problem is that the template should be updated in Xamarin Studio so this warning does not appear.

**Warning: Redundant method override** - This means that the method is not doing anything. In your code it is just calling the base.OnCreate method so this warning is telling you that your new method is not doing anything. If you add some custom code in your OnCreate method then this warning will go away.

Comment: Thanks a lot man for the help and explanation, That's quite strange that xamarin studio isn't updating the base class method call.